# How to add the ImageMagick install to my path on Ubuntu

Tags: imagemagick

I have had been on a roller coaster trying to get ImageMagick to work on my Ubuntu slice. I Whenever I try to upload an image I get the following error: /tmp/stream.1170.0 is not recognized by the 'identify' command.

If I type 'which identify' I get: /usr/local/bin/identify

If I run '/usr/local/bin/identify' or just 'identify', I get the following error: /usr/local/bin/identify: error while loading shared libraries: libMagickCore.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

If I run '/usr/bin/identify', ImageMagick is run just fine. How can I set my path to where when Paperclip runs the identify command, it points to /usr/bin/identify? Thanks.

p.s. I have tried adding this to paperclip.rb: Paperclip.options[:command_path] = '/usr/bin' and Paperclip.options[:command_path] = '/usr/local/bin'

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib to your environment.

Alternatively, you can install ImageMagick from repositories, it should work out-of-the-box:

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
```

Answer (score 4):

I got it installed as follows (on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS):

```
$ sudo apt-get install imagemagick libmagickwand-dev
```

This installs the ImageMagick on your machine.

You may now check its version as follows:

```
$ convert -version
```

Installation directory: /usr/bin (you can find “convert” tool here)

```
$ which convert
```

/usr/bin/convert

Answer (score 3):

Please follow the below steps otherwise.

```
$ sudo apt update 
$ sudo apt-get install build-essential

$ wget https://www.imagemagick.org/download/ImageMagick.tar.gz
$ tar xvzf ImageMagick.tar.gz

$ cd ImageMagick-7.0.8-26/
```

To run configuration and to compile

```
$./configure 
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

To create link,

```
$ sudo ldconfig /usr/local/lib
```

Check version

```
$ magick -version
```

Thanks to Aaron Kili, Author of the below article.

Source: https://www.tecmint.com/install-imagemagick-on-debian-ubuntu/

Answer (score 2):

To get rid of this error i executed
ldconfig /usr/local/lib

Comment: Thanks! This is what I needed to do when I had the same problem. (Why isn't this command in the make install target?)

Comment: Thank you. I am using RHEL5 so I had to compile from source and This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer using aptitude:

```
sudo aptitude update
sudo aptitude install imagemagick
```

and you're fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can also install it using `Software Manager`

[image: /home/john/Desktop/Screenshot from 2020-05-30 16-43-33.png]